# Managing Multiple Git Repos / Forks

Tags: git, version-control, github, workflow

I have a situation in git that I would like some advice on how to manage properly.

I currently have a fork of HTML5 boilerplate that I am working with for my own needs and have the upstream added to pull in commits from the html5boilerplate master repo.

I am going to be using this fork for a separate project that will change form very drastically from what html5boilerplate currently is but I would also like to pull in changes from the master repo as they happen.

My questions are:

Should I pull another fork of html5boilerplate and name respectively based on my new project (adding upstream for changes to master)?

Should I create another fork of my fork of html5boilerplate and pull in upstream from my original fork of the html5boilerplate (this sounds too complex)?

Would branching be a suffice way to manage this workflow?

Is there a more effective way of doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about your local repository, you can safely fork locally and never push back the changes to your branch. The rest is a matter of taste.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your reply, I will be working with a team on this project so pushing back to GitHub is necessary.

Comment: Well, then again, it's completely a matter of taste — have your repository and branch in it.

Comment: I am mainly looking for best practice in the scenario, I have a couple ideas as listed above but not too confident / sure on any of them.

Comment: There's none. I see definitely no reason whatsoever to make two forks.

Comment: After thinking about it more I agree and see why. Thank you.